# Filtering a list based on sed and awk command, multiple delimiter

Tags: awk, sed, delimiter, cut

I need help in this issue.
I have some files in a folder and I want to list it, but I want to list only the main Cours-name.

```
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 01.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 02.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 03.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 04.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 05.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 06.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 07.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 08.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 09.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 10.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Bauch-Beine-Po 11.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Entspannung.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 01.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 02.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 03.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 04.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 05.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 06.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:35 'Gymnastik - Muskeln wie Stahl 07.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - RückenFit 01.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - RückenFit 02.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - RückenFit 03.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - RückenFit 04.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - RückenFit 05.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Stretching 01.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Stretching 02.mp4'
-r--r----- 1 saeid azubi 0 Jun 10 14:34 'Gymnastik - Stretching 03.mp4'
```

here

The output should be like this :

> Bauch-Beine-Po
>
> Entspannung
>
> Muskeln wie Stahl
>
> RückenFit
>
> Stretching

I tried this code but its not what exactly what I want:

```
ls -l | awk -F'[ .\$]' '{print $11 }' | uniq
```

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Why the image. Is it so hard to obtain the text in it and paste it?

Comment: Parsing `ls` output is clunky.

Comment: When you cannot accurately describe the intended output, you cannot program it.

Comment: you are right @Roadowl, im sorry im new here and i have been under stress. Is it clear what im looking for now! Thnanks

Comment: Hi @SaeidHerawi, welcome to the site! I'm sure your problem will be solved if you paste in the text you show in the image - then we can copy the text to our systems and work on a command to get the names you need from it. It's much harder for us to do that if we don't get the text (few people will take the time to manually type the example in the image to work on it, and few people will be so confident to provide an answer that they only _think_ will work but haven't tested on their system).

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer, i have been working hard last night to find the right answer and finely i found it. But thank you so much for your concern :)

Comment: ls -lrtA |cut -f11-13 -d ' '| sed  's/[0-9]*\.[^.]*$//'| sort | uniq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also use awk.

Use  `-`  as the field separator and remove the optional space and digits followed by the extension from the last field.

For example

```
ls -A1 | awk -F ' - ' '{sub(/( [0-9]+)?\.[^.]+$/, "", $NF);print $NF}' | sort | uniq
```

In the example code:

- `$NF` is the last field, which will first be changed by sub and then printed
- The pattern `( [0-9]+)?\.[^.]+$` matches an optional space and 1+ digits followed by a dot and any char except a dot until the end of the string

Answer (score -1):

here is finelly what i wanted

```
ls -lrtA |cut -f11-13 -d ' '| sed  's/[0-9]*\.[^.]*$//'| sort | uniq
```